# "En forme de" with plural ?

Tags: accord, pluriel

I'm looking for the correct manner to use "en forme de" in a plural context.

Let's take an example: should we write “des lunettes en forme de cœur” or “des lunettes en forme de cœurs”?

A quick search on ngram doesn't return any result for the second manner, but I'm still in doubt :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are referring to the "shape of a couple of hearts" so the plural is definitely correct in French :

> Des lunettes en forme de cœurs.

Google Ngram finds some occurrences of *en forme de cœurs* but you need to use the proper spelling: *c**œ**ur* not *c**oe**ur*.

[image]

Here are example of plural following *en forme de* from [wikipedia](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_forme_de):

> Ces tanks, situés contre la digue, au sud […] de la borne 15, sont deux immenses réservoirs à pétrole en forme de gazomètres, déjà troués comme des écumoires, […]. — (Marguerite Baulu, La Bataille de l'Yser, Paris, Perrin & Cie, 1918, p.247)

and from [Alain Decaux (Académie Française)](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/discours-de-reception-dalain-decaux):

> À l’horizon, des îles en forme de rochers noirs ponctuent la limite du gris de l’eau et du ciel pâle.

Comment: referring to the shape of a couple of hearts is not English. Et franchement, pourquoi dire: en forme de coeurs? Le fait que cela se trouve ne prouve pas que c'est la traduction de heart-shaped [x]. Et puis, des îles, pluriel n'est la question. Je veux dire, une question qui concerne la forme d'un truc quelconque au pluriel.

Comment: @Lambie Je viens de mettre *the shape of a couple of hearts* entre guillemets si ce n'est pas anglais. La forme du truc quelconque est celle de **deux cœurs**, d'où l'acceptation du pluriel mais le singulier serait plus logique avec « des lunettes en forme de papillon ». D'autre part, je n'ai pas écrit que le singulier était impossible ou incorrect avec cœur, seulement que le pluriel était correct.

Comment: Le problème c'est que la question est mal formulée en anglais. L'adjectif en anglais heart-shaped devient en forme de coeur. Deux petits pains en forme de coeur. deux coeurs c'est different de deux trucs en ***forme de coeur***. Deux petits pains, chacun en forme de coeur. Il me semble que en formes de coeurs serait pour la pâtisserie. Mais même lá, on trouve plutôt en forme de coeur. En forme triangulaire. En forme de triangle. En forme circulaire. Tout cela, ce sont des idées sur la forme, alors je vois mal pourquoi on le mettrait au pluriel.

Comment: @Lambie Parce qu'il y en a deux. Je préfère beaucoup « des lunettes en forme d'yeux » à « des lunettes en forme d'œil ».

Comment: Qui dirait cela? Un oeil n'est pas consideré une forme à vrai dire.....un oeil n'est pas une forme. Et puis l'adjectif pour un oeil est oculaire.....si tu veux porter des lunettes en forme oculaire, be my guest. :)

Comment: @Lambie http://www.festimania.fr/lunettes/4836-lunettes-yeux-globuleux.html http://www.happyfete.com/Grande-lunettes-mouche.html https://www.veritas.be/eshop/be_fr/F-10006-brillen/P-1306687-

Answer (score 1):

C'est bien en forme de cœur**S**. Une paire de lunettes est composée de deux lunettes. Chaque lunette a une forme de cœur. Comme celles de Lolita sur l'affiche du Film de Kubrick. On les voit bien les 2 cœurs :)  :
                                                            [image: Sweet Lolita]
S'il s'agissait d'une patate, vous écririez:

> Une patate en forme de cœur. On voit bien un seul cœur ;)  [image]

Si vous vous posez la même question pour:

> Un mur en pierre

Sachez que vous pouvez mettre pierre au singulier comme au pluriel. Au singulier, la *pierre* est la **matière** du mur. Au pluriel, Les pierres constituent le mur, le mur est fait de plusieurs pierres. Dans la tête du lecteur se forment deux images différentes. Ça marche aussi avec *de*.

NB: non, je ne peux me résoudre à considérer le cœur comme une matière (ce qui pourrait faire croire qu'on puisse l'écrire au singulier pour les lunettes aussi). Dans "Rodrigue as-tu du cœur" ? On ne parle pas du même cœur. Chez les bouchers ? L'image produite me dégoûte un peu.

Comment: Le problème c'est qu'on ne connait pas ce qui est en forme de coeur. Heart-shaped glasses, et heart-shaped lenses in glasses. Bien sûre, au pluriel. Mais pas un dessin en forme de coeur. Alors, tout dépend du vouloir-dire.

Comment: Le cœur, c’est le grand symbole de la Saint Valentin ! Cette fête peu appréciée, peu célébrée, considérée ringarde, nous permet cependant de ***découvrir de jolis objets en forme de cœur***: Des lampes en papier, des coussins, des cintres et des housses de couette avec un imprimé « cœur » qui trouveront parfaitement leurs places dans les chambres de nos petites filles. http://blogs.cotemaison.fr/moltodeco/2015/01/22/20-objets-en-forme-de-coeur/

Comment: Même deux patates en forme de coeur font une forme au singulier.

Comment: Vous pouvez garder le singulier. Ce n'est pas une faute. Vous diriez "une paire de lunettes en forme de cheval" ou "une paires de lunettes en forme de chevaux" ? Je voterais pour la 2ème. Et pour une lampe et bien ça dépendra de la lampe, il faut que je l'aie sous mes lunettes tout à fait ordinaires ;)

Comment: On peut arriver au ridicule, si on veut...

Comment: J'ai choisi *cheval* simplement pour son pluriel en *aux*. Merci pour votre remarque.